# Cakephp 3 get last query executed

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I've been trying to handle exceptions on cakephp 3 when querying to database.

I would like to get the last query executed when and exception is fired to notify by email to an administrator, i'm using MySQL database so the error code would be nice to have it too if possible.

This is my code right now.

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
  $opciones=$this->request->data;

  $configsTable = TableRegistry::get('Configs');      

  try{        

    $configsTable->connection()->transactional(function() use($configsTable, $opciones){
      foreach ($opciones as $llave => $opcion) {
        $q = $configsTable->find('all', [
          'conditions' => [
            'Configs.nombre' => $llave
          ]
        ]);
        $reg = $q->first();

        if (empty($reg)) {
          $data = array();
          $data['nombre'] = $llave;
          $data['valor'] = $opcion;

          $entity = $configsTable->newEntity($data);


          if (!$configsTable->save($entity, ['atomic' => false])) {


            /********trying to catch database error here******/                

            throw new \Exception(__('Error message'));
          }

        }else{
          $u = $configsTable->updateAll(['valor'=>$opcion], [
            'id'=>$reg->id
          ]); 

          if(!$u){                                 

            /********trying to catch database error here******/                

            throw new \Exception(__('Error message'));
          }
        }
      }
    });

    $this->Flash->success(__('Ajustes actualizados'),[
      'params'=>['class'=>'alert-absolute timed', 'tiempo'=>5]
    ]);

  } catch (\PDOException $ex) {
    $this->Flash->error($ex->getCode().' - '.$ex->getMessage(),[
      //'params'=>['class'=>'alert-absolute timed', 'tiempo'=>5]
    ]);
  } catch (\Exception $ex){
    $this->Flash->error($ex->getMessage(),[
      //'params'=>['class'=>'alert-absolute timed', 'tiempo'=>5]
    ]);
  }
}
```

I'm still searching on cookbook for some information. Thaks.

Answer (score 0):

Let the `PDOException` be handled by the error handler (which is done by default). You can setup [your own error handler](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#extending-and-implementing-your-own-exception-handlers) which checks exception type and sends email in case of `PDOException`.

You can get the sql query using exception instance as `$error->queryString`.